# How can I order my query by criteria (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query.

```
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE
FROM AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
ORDER BY R.FILESTATEID
```

The values of FileStateID are:

- 140
- 160
- 190
- 200
- 5

I want that order of select is this:

First the records that have FileStateID = 200
then the records with FileStateID = 140
then the records with FileStateID = 5
..
..

How can I order my select with this mode?

Comment: duplicate of [Is it possible to select a specific ORDER BY in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208104/is-it-possible-to-select-a-specific-order-by-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column where you order them and then use it in the order by clause,
something like this :

```
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE,
Case
when R.FileStateID = 200 then 1,
when R.FileStateID = 140 then 2, 
when R.FileStateID = 5   then 3,
when R.FileStateID = 160 then 4 
ELSE 0 END AS order_
FROM AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
ORDER BY order_
```

Comment: Good approach, but I guess it won't work. You need to create `order_` column in subquery :)

Comment: No you don't have to. Just try it and if it doesn't work let me know so I could post another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to hard code the order sequence in the `ORDER BY clause`, you can have a table that defines the order sequence for each FileStatID. Then your query will be simply

```
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE
FROM  AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
      INNER JOIN FILESTAT F ON R.FILESTATEID = F.FILESTATEID
ORDER BY F.SEQ_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE
FROM AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
WHERE R.FILESTATEID = 200
UNION ALL
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE
FROM AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
WHERE R.FILESTATEID = 140
UNION ALL
SELECT R.ID, R.DESCRIZIONE
FROM AA_V_ATS_RICHIESTE R
WHERE R.FILESTATEID = 5
UNION ALL
...
```