# Can't order by name when use Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm using following SQL query to insert data to temp table

```
INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify 
    SELECT     'U' + CONVERT(varchar,UserId), CONVERT([varchar](50), [FirstName]) + ' ' + CONVERT([varchar](50), [LastName])
    FROM  [User] 
            INNER JOIN dbo.UserGroup ON UserId = FkUserId  
            INNER JOIN [Group] ON GroupId = FkGroupId 
    GROUP BY UserId, CONVERT([varchar](50), [FirstName]), CONVERT([varchar](50), [LastName])
    HAVING MIN(GroupLevel) >= @minGroup
    ORDER BY CONVERT([varchar](50), [FirstName]), CONVERT([varchar](50), [LastName])
```

I'm inserting several data as follows,

Inserting group data as

```
INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify 
    SELECT     'G' + CONVERT(varchar,GroupId), 'Group - ' + GroupName
    FROM  [Group] 
    WHERE GroupLevel >= @minGroup AND IsActive = 1
    ORDER BY GroupName
```

So I need to display user name list first then group names order by GroupName.

My full code is

```
    --Users of the same group as currently logged in user and userÆs of higher groups
    INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify 
        SELECT     'U' + CONVERT(varchar,UserId), CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([FirstName])) + ' ' + CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([LastName]))
        FROM  [User] 
                INNER JOIN dbo.UserGroup ON UserId = FkUserId  
                INNER JOIN [Group] ON GroupId = FkGroupId 
        GROUP BY UserId, CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([FirstName])), CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([LastName]))
        HAVING MIN(GroupLevel) >= @minGroup
        ORDER BY CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([FirstName])), CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY([LastName]))

    select * from @tmp_Notify

    --Currently logged in userÆs group and higher groups
    INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify 
        SELECT     'G' + CONVERT(varchar,GroupId), 'Group - ' + GroupName
        FROM  [Group] 
        WHERE GroupLevel >= @minGroup AND IsActive = 1
--      GROUP BY GroupId, GroupName
--      HAVING MIN(GroupLevel) >= @minGroup
        ORDER BY GroupName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify VALUES('Me','Me')

    IF((SELECT FkSupervisor FROM [User] WHERE UserId = @currentUser) IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify VALUES('Supervisor','Supervisor')
    END
END

    --List Option (to allow a list of email addresses)
    INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify VALUES('List','List')   

    --SELECT * FROM @tmp_Notify tn order by tn.NotifyName
    SELECT * FROM @tmp_Notify
```

But its not order to correct way, I need to sort data by `FirstName` and `LastName`. How can I do it

My expected output is

```
U10059  Emily Windrow
U10039  Esta Kulzer
U10030  Ileana Conklin
U10040  Kamala Millerbernd
U10007  Katherine Tayan
G110    Group - Managers
G112    Group - Membership Officers
G113    Group - Mortgage
G108    Group - Operations Administrator
G109    Group - PFS
List    List
```

Comment: Why do you want to order your insert?

Comment: Because Insert serveral data as above, So I need to take final result by order name

Comment: If you need your *final* result to be in a specific order, then the `ORDER BY` goes in the `SELECT` statement, not the `INSERT`.

Comment: But sorting your insert doesn't have any effect at all (except slowing the query down). The only way to sort your data is by using `order by` when you query the table

Comment: @Larnu Problem is I insert several data to that table, such as user name list first, then groups ,

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output from them?

Comment: @Larnu please see my updated question , u can see I'm inserting several data. I need to Sort data By Name in final result, But Group data should need to come after sorted names

Comment: *"I need to Sort data By Name in final result"* And again, that would be in your `SELECT {Columns} FROM @tmp_Notify` statement, not your `INSERT INTO @tmp_Notify` statement.

Comment: @mkRabbani I added sir, Please see my updated question

Comment: @Larnu can please check my updated question and give me an answer

Comment: @thomsan, the answer is; if you want to sort your final result, use `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` query (as mentioned a couple of times now).

Comment: I don't need to post an answer, @thomsan, as your question makes no sense. As i've said, the order you `INSERT` the data has no reflection on the order you `SELECT` it. If you need your final result set in a specific order, then add the `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT`. The problem has **nothing** to do with the `INSERT`.

Comment: Yeah I did it as `SELECT * FROM @tmp_Notify tn order by tn.NotifyName` But I need to get user name list first, then Group names and finally `List` please see my expected output

Comment: What you can do, is add an `IDENTITY` column to your table, and use that to sort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this is a simple misunderstanding. The OP needs to put their `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement, not try and order the `INSERT`. This is effectively equivalent to **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. As a result, the question is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can please give me a sample code, If I use Identity column, How can I query it to take expected output

Comment: What you probably wanted was a Select statement- using an ORDER BY with a CASE Statement.  Attempting ordering in the insert is ridiculous and practically no one does this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208104/is-it-possible-to-select-a-specific-order-by-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want using something similar to this:

```
DECLARE @tmp_Notify TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), FirstName VARCHAR(50), lastname VARCHAR(50))

INSERT @tmp_Notify (FirstName, lastname)
VALUES ( 'Bob', 'Curtis')
,       ('Mary', 'Magdalene')

INSERT @tmp_Notify (FirstName, lastname)
VALUES ( 'GROUP', '1')
,       ('GROUP', '2')

INSERT @tmp_Notify (FirstName, lastname)
VALUES ( 'List', 'List')

SELECT  TN.id
,       TN.FirstName
,       TN.lastname
FROM    @tmp_Notify AS TN
ORDER BY TN.id
```

In this case you can use an `ORDER BY` in your `INSERT`, because that will determine the value of `id`.

Comment: Thank for save my life sir

Comment: Suppose If I add additional column as IdentityColm and insert `A`,`B`,`C` as each userm group data inserting. So then can I sort it by name by grouping ?

Comment: Suppose If I add additional column as IdentityColm and insert `A`,`B`,`C` as each user group data inserting. So then can I sort it by name by grouping ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, it might be worth asking a new question

Comment: And then what happens when someone marries and changes their last name?  In that case their name is out of order with respect to the identity column.  Also- what if someone new needs to be added?  When we insert, the identity value increments but this has no relation to someone's name or whether it is in order.

Comment: @Zorkolot, considering OP is dealing with a table variable, I don't think changes like that are expected. Any changes in the tables selected from will be correctly reflected in the table variable. Otherwise, yes, completely valid points.

Comment: If a different ordering is ever required then this sort of technique requires an entire re-write of the stored procedure to serve the identity.  An ordering number is not part of the expected output...  Also, OP's already shaky understanding of SQL is clear to many of us and I don't think this sets him on the right path (to attempt ordering in inserts).

Answer (score 2):

This is a common misconception.

Adding an order to an insert statement has no meaning because a raw table of data has no inherent guaranteed order to it. Within SQL Server regardless of the order the data goes in it will be stored within the clustered index and thus ordered by that. It will also be added to any other indexes in the table which might be different again. If you have no indexes at all and your table is a heap then the order will have no certainty to it whatever you do.

When you come to query a table there is no default guaranteed order the data will be returned in *unless* you specify it with ORDER BY. Without this the returned data can in theory be in any order (SQL Server will output in whatever order allows it to complete the query in the fastest time).

The order you put data in to a table has no bearing on the order you will get it back out again.